# Is it possible to include Mime Type inside a SVG file

Tags: svg, mime-types

My goal is to serve a whole range of logo under the same link base whether it is a PNG or a SVG. For instance: association 452 would have it's logo at https://foo.bar/association-32/small. Hence, I would like to serve a SVG file without extension (e.g logos/picture).

However, the mime type is not working when I do that, and I do not know if it is possible to include the Mime type in the file (or to make the server understand it's a image/svg+xml). It would allow the HTTP request to have the correct header, and the image to be displayed properly.

I tried with sym links but it did not worked (on windows at least). I do not want to involve database.

Is there anything I am missing, or another solution to look at ?

Have a great day.

Comment: Depends on the web server you're using to serve the SVG files.

Comment: HTTP request: Somehow you need to tell the server what kind of image you are requesting. If not in the URL, then in the header. You can use the accept header for that (like: `Accept: image/svg+xml`). HTTP response: In any case you probably need some business logic (code...) to handle the request. Here you can also set the content-type header. Be aware that the caching in the browser can be an issue. It will assume that a URL is a specific resource, so disable caching using headers as well.

Comment: For requesting the image try to set a preload in the `<head>`: `<link rel="preload" href="/association-32/small" as="image" type="image/svg+xml">`. This will set the accept header to `image/svg+xml`. And then you can refer to the image as you normally would in `<body>`: `<img src="/association-32/small">`. You still need the web server to figure out what image to return.